# biblatex: How to set maxbibname to different values in different refsections?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, author-number

I have a document with several `refsections`. In one of them I'd like to set `maxbibnames=99` (or rather: keep the value global set in the preamble), but in another I'd like to set `maxbibnames=3`.

Is that possible?

(A workaround in which I manually edit the 5 to 10 bibentries with too many authors in the .bib-file would be ok, but changing the actual names in these entries is what I'd like to avoid.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible. You can redefine `\blx@maxbibnames` for the desired `refsection`; using the `\Setmaxbibnames` command, you can locally specify the desired value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Setmaxbibnames[1]{\renewcommand\blx@maxbibnames{#1}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{almendro}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\Setmaxbibnames{3}
\cite{almendro}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{almendro}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that my case is a bit more complicated. I realized that I am not using `\maxbibnames` to reduce the number of authors but  `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{maxnames=2}` and it looks like that is your `\Setmaxbibnames` does not overpower that...