# How can I change the Biblatex options `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` temporarily in the text?

Tags: biblatex

For a certain part of my document, I'd like to change the `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` options of `Biblatex`. Afterwards, I'd like these options to go back to their default values.

I've dug around in the Biblatex manual and I think I'd like to use a command like `\AtEveryCite`. However, it's specified in the manual that this command only can be used in the preamble.

---

Update:

I have the following macro defined elsewhere:

```
% For creating \nparencite which create a parencite output without the parantheses.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nparencite}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2       \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
```

I didn't write it myself, so I have no understanding of the logic behind it.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374059/3555) answer to another question, @David Puron defines a new macro where he messes around with parameters similar to those that I need to mess around with. Maybe if I could somehow incorporate his solution into my code?

Comment: Do you want it for all citations within a particular part of the document, or particular citations only?

Comment: @AlanMunn All of them. In my specific case, it's a table where I can't fit citations with to many names in them.

Comment: You can do `\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{minnames}{1}\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}` (or whatever numbers you want) to change the counters for the next cite command.

Comment: A really quick and dirty way would be to create a `\shortcite` macro: `\newcommand{\shortcite}[1]{\citeauthor*{#1} \mkbibparens{\citeyear{#1}}}`. In this form it will work only with a single bib key; to do it properly you'd need to make a proper `biblatex` macro.

Comment: Obviously @moewe 's version is much better, so combine the two: `\newcommand{\shortcite}{\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{minnames}{1}\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}}
\textcite}`

Comment: Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127773/105447 or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374046/105447 help?

Comment: Both suggestions unfortunately gives me `! Undefined control sequence.` errors when trying to run them. Otherwise, I like the idea of creating new citation commands for these special cases. However, I am already using custom made citation commands, so I don't know if there will be a risk of interference between them.

Comment: @gusbrs Kinda. I already have a \DeclareCiteCommand block that I could copy and slightly modify to restrict number of cite names. However, I can't for the life figure out how to modify it.

Comment: @Speldosa, if you update your question with a proper [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography), I'll incorporate my answer mentioned above for you.

Comment: At this point you definitely need to add a MWEB, because there's no obvious reason why @moewe 's answer (or my macro version of it) shouldn't work.

Comment: @Speldosa, both the first of David's alternatives and my own answer in the link allow you to set directly `maxcitenames` locally. With them you shouldn't need to adapt your `\DeclareCiteCommand` I believe.

Comment: Off-topic: if you don't understand the logic behind your `\nparencite` command and you just use it to have "a parencite output without the parantheses" I suggest you try the regular `\cite` command...

Comment: Still, if you follow David's offer and Alan's advice supplying a MWE, it will be certainly a lot easier to help.

Comment: `\AtEachCitekey` was added fairly recently, so if my solution fails with `! Undefined control sequence.` your `biblatex` version might be outdated.

Comment: Turns out 'fairly recently' was end of December 2015. You will need at least version 3.2 of `biblatex` for this to work. What version of `biblatex` do your run?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Per-section bibliography styling using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374046/35864) because you settled on that solution. Or are you interested in finding out why Alan's and my solution did not work for you?

Comment: Any news here? Would you say that your question is a duplicate or not?